# Why I can't order temporary table in MySQL procedure?

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL procedure, which forms temporary table `ResultTabl` and at the end show it for user:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stop_factor_addition (IN fromDate varchar(100), IN toDate varchar(100))
BEGIN

DECLARE week VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE curWeek VARCHAR(100) default '';
DECLARE stopfactor VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE countdeals int;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE WeekFactors (name varchar(100));
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE WeekFactorsDifference (name varchar(100));
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ResultTabl (week varchar(100), stopfactor varchar(100), countdeals int);

...
...

select * from ResultTabl;
END
```

Result is:

[image: before order]

But I want to order by week field. I add `order by week` on select statement :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE stop_factor_addition (IN fromDate varchar(100), IN toDate varchar(100))
BEGIN

DECLARE week VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE curWeek VARCHAR(100) default '';
DECLARE stopfactor VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE countdeals int;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE WeekFactors (name varchar(100));
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE WeekFactorsDifference (name varchar(100));
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ResultTabl (week varchar(100), stopfactor varchar(100), countdeals int);

...
...

select * from ResultTabl order by week;
END
```

But nothing changes:

[image: after order]

Why `order by` not work on this temporary table?

Comment: Does this work `SELECT r. * FROM ResultTabl AS r ORDER BY r. week;`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yes, it works! But what kind of magic?

Comment: You have a variable name `week`. It seems like this is used that to order by, when you don't qualify `week` as being from the table. An since the variable `week` is constant during the query it's effectively not sorting at all.

Comment: Mu wild guwss was what stickybit said. The variable named `week` confused MySQL's parser. I think this counts as a bug and you should report it.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. Yes, I report this issue to MySQL.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, or at least a known one. From ["13.6.4.2 Local Variable Scope and Resolution"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html): "A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If an SQL statement, such as a `SELECT ... INTO` statement, contains a reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a variable."

Comment: Alternatively, use backtics:   `\`week\``

Comment: @sticky bit Yes, MySQL clearly point don't use the same name, it's my fault. Now it's doesn't seem as a bug.